# Is it good practice to have a setter return a bool?

Tags: java, c++

For example, consider the two following setters:

```
bool setMonth(int month) {
    bool valid = false;
    if (month > 0 && month < 12) {
        this->month = month;
        valid = true;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

versus

```
void setMonth(int month) {
   if (month > 0 && month < 12) {
      this->month = month;
   }
}
```

The first one lets the client of the class know explicitly whether the set failed. Is this considered good practice?

Comment: Is it a good practice to have setter at all?

Comment: Please only use the language tag for the language you're actually programming it.

Comment: it is a none idiomatic usage of a setter, so nobody would look for/expect that. Imo throwing an IllegalArgumentException would be better.

Comment: Please pick a language. Only tag two languages if expertise in both languages is required to answer.

Comment: First of all, neither of these is valid Java, and  you should not tag your question as such.  Secondly, as this question is primarily an opinion-based one, it is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: And the answer is no, returning `bool` is a terrible idea. The best answer is to create a *user defined type* (class) for *month* that simply can not have an incorrect value. The next best thing is either *assert* or an exception.

Comment: @Galik either a class or a namespace

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so. This would mean that anytime you set something, you have to check whether the operation was successful or not.
I think raising an exception would be a better idea, for readability and logic.
I find that:

```
/*program stuff*/
try{
    YourObject.setMonth(0);
    /* other stuff*/
}catch YourException{
/* recovery*/
}
```

Is cleaner that:

```
/*program stuff*/
if(!YourObject.setMonth(0)){
    /*recovery*/
}else{
    /*stuff*/
}
```

In terms of logic (I would say philosophy) and readability.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's cleaner, but it's definitely more useful, since an `Exception` object can give you information on the issue, or even pass other data if needed. It also shows intent of error handling, rather than ordinary control flow branching.

Comment: By "cleaner" I meant avoiding the control flow branching, my bad. And yeah, `Exception` objects can provide a lot of useful information!

Answer (score 3):

One could argue that using `boolean` as a return type does not hurt. In The worst case you just ignore the check.

Another one could argue that throwing an exception is more elegant and more informative too (like Java's `IllegalArgumentException` or Python's `ValueError`), however this may result in more "trouble" as exceptions have to be handled one way or another from client code.

A third approach, if you need to be sure that the inserted values are absolutely correct, is to encapsulate allowed values in structural entities such as classes, enums or namespaces.
An example in Java would be:

```
public void setMonth(Month month){
    this.month = month;     // member month is now of type Month
}


public enum Month{

    JANUARY(1),
    FEBRUARY(2),
    MARCH(3),
    APRIL(4),
    MAY(5),
    JUNE(6),
    JULY(7),
    AUGUST(8),
    SEPTEMBER(9),
    OCTOBER(10),
    NOVEMBER(11),
    DECEMBER(12)


    private int n;
    private Month(int n){
        this.n = n;
    }
}
```

and the way of using that would be:

```
someObject.setMonth(Month.FEBRUARY);
```

(You can achieve the same thing with a namespace in C++.)

Answer (score 2):

Better use exceptions in setters when you want to track invalid data inserted to them. In this case signature of method is:

```
//throw exception when month is out of range 
    void setMonth(int month) throws InvalidMonthNumberException;
```

In case you want to setup default data when month is out of range discribe this in javadoc.

```
/*
* If month < 1 or month > 12 default month (1) accepted
*/
void setMonth(int month);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is java (you tagged two language) then best practice is return void from setter. In case of failed to set value then throw exception. For your case, you should throw `IllegalArgumentException` of month setter.